# zipWithIndex on Apache Flink

Tags: scala, apache-flink

I'd like to assign each row of my input an `id` - which should be a number from `0` to `N - 1`, where `N` is the number of rows in the input.

Roughly, I'd like to be able to do something like the following :

```scala
val data = sc.textFile(textFilePath, numPartitions)
val rdd = data.map(line => process(line))
val rddMatrixLike = rdd.zipWithIndex.map { case (v, idx) => someStuffWithIndex(idx, v) }
```

But in Apache Flink. Is it possible?

Comment: Thats an interesting question. I'll try to come up with an implementation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is now a part of the 0.10-SNAPSHOT release of Apache Flink. Examples for `zipWithIndex(in)` and `zipWithUniqueId(in)` are available in the official [Flink documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/apis/zip_elements_guide.html).

Answer (score 5):

Here is a simple implementation of the function:

```
public class ZipWithIndex {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    ExecutionEnvironment ee = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

    DataSet<String> in = ee.readTextFile("/home/robert/flink-workdir/debug/input");

    // count elements in each partition
    DataSet<Tuple2<Integer, Long>> counts = in.mapPartition(new RichMapPartitionFunction<String, Tuple2<Integer, Long>>() {
        @Override
        public void mapPartition(Iterable<String> values, Collector<Tuple2<Integer, Long>> out) throws Exception {
            long cnt = 0;
            for (String v : values) {
                cnt++;
            }
            out.collect(new Tuple2<Integer, Long>(getRuntimeContext().getIndexOfThisSubtask(), cnt));
        }
    });

    DataSet<Tuple2<Long, String>> result = in.mapPartition(new RichMapPartitionFunction<String, Tuple2<Long, String>>() {
        long start = 0;

        @Override
        public void open(Configuration parameters) throws Exception {
            super.open(parameters);
            List<Tuple2<Integer, Long>> offsets = getRuntimeContext().getBroadcastVariable("counts");
            Collections.sort(offsets, new Comparator<Tuple2<Integer, Long>>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(Tuple2<Integer, Long> o1, Tuple2<Integer, Long> o2) {
                    return ZipWithIndex.compare(o1.f0, o2.f0);
                }
            });
            for(int i = 0; i < getRuntimeContext().getIndexOfThisSubtask(); i++) {
                start += offsets.get(i).f1;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void mapPartition(Iterable<String> values, Collector<Tuple2<Long, String>> out) throws Exception {
            for(String v: values) {
                out.collect(new Tuple2<Long, String>(start++, v));
            }
        }
    }).withBroadcastSet(counts, "counts");
    result.print();

}

public static int compare(int x, int y) {
    return (x < y) ? -1 : ((x == y) ? 0 : 1);
}
}
```

This is how it works: I'm using the first `mapPartition()` operation to go over all elements in the partitions to count how many elements are in there.
I need to know the number of elements in each partition to properly set the offsets when assigning the IDs to the elements.
The result of the first `mapPartition` is a DataSet containing  mappings. I'm broadcasting this DataSet to all the second `mapPartition()` operators which will assign the IDs to the elements from the input.
In the `open()` method of the second `mapPartition()` I'm computing the offset for each partition.

I'm probably going to contribute the code to Flink (after discussing it with the other committers).

Comment: Thanks Robert! Could you also maybe explain in a few words how this works? E.g. why do we use `getRuntimeContext().getIndexOfThisSubtask()` and why broadcasting counts of each partition could help?

Comment: Is there a Jira issue for zipWithIndex? I'd like to follow it to know if/when it's going to be a part of Flink

Comment: Maybe with `zipWithIndex` added to Flink codebase you could update the answer?