# How can I implement zipWithIndex like Spark in Apache Beam?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-beam

```
Pcollection<String> p1 = {"a","b","c"}

PCollection< KV<Integer,String> > p2 = p1.apply("some operation ") 
//{(1,"a"),(2,"b"),(3,"c")}
```

I need to make it scalable for large file like Apache Spark such that it works like:

```
sc.textFile("./filename").zipWithIndex
```

My goal is to preserve the order between rows within a large file by assigning row numbers in a scalable way.

How can I get the result by Apache Beam?

Some related posts:
[zipWithIndex on Apache Flink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30596556/zipwithindex-on-apache-flink)

[Ranking pcollection elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48284526/ranking-pcollection-elements)

Comment: this is apache beam question, remove spark & scala & java & scala-collections tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(copying [my response from user@beam.apache.org](https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/5c10b7edf982ef63d1d1d70545e3fe2716d00628ff5c2a7854383413@%3Cuser.beam.apache.org%3E))*

This is interesting. So if I understand your algorithm, it would be something like (pseudocode):

```
A = ReadWithShardedLineNumbers(myFile) : output K<ShardOffset+LocalLineNumber>, V<Data>
B = A.ExtractShardOffsetKeys() : output K<ShardOffset>, V<LocalLineNumber>
C = B.PerKeySum() : output K<ShardOffset>, V<ShardTotalLines>
D = C.GlobalSortAndPrefixSum() : output K<ShardOffset> V<ShardLineNumberOffset>
E = [A,D].JoinAndCalculateGlobalLineNumbers() : output V<GlobalLineNumber+Data>
```

This makes a couple assumptions:

1. `ReadWithShardedLineNumbers`: Sources can output their shard offset, and the offsets are globally ordered
2. `GlobalSortAndPrefixSum`: The totals for all read shards can fit in memory to perform a total sort

Assumption #2 will not hold true for all data sizes, and varies by runner depending on how granular the read shards are. But it seems feasible for some practical subset of file-sizes.

Also, I believe the pseudo-code above is representable in Beam, and would not require SplittableDoFn.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in way to do this. `PCollections` in Beam are unordered, potentially unbounded and are processed in parallel on multiple workers. The fact that the `PCollection` comes out of a source with known order cannot be observed in Beam model directly. I think the easier way would be to preprocess the file before it is consumed in the Beam pipeline.

Comment: Are there any way to read from one data source(a large file) in contiguous way into multiple `PCollections` with known number of lines, and access each `PCollection` by its `id`?  

I am not sure whether this can be done in declarative programming / graph construction approach in formulating the pipeline.

Comment: There is nothing like that built in that works, as far as I know. Problem with that approach is that the split has to happen dynamically. I.e. if the pipeline runner decides to throw more machines at it, multiple machines might start loading the same parts of the file. Ideally you would want to rebalance the load in this case. Granted, runners might allow you to specify the parallelism you want, but using these flags to solve this problem would be wrong.

Comment: Semi-good news are that `SplittableDoFn` is probably going to address this use case https://beam.apache.org/blog/2017/08/16/splittable-do-fn.html . The idea there is that the `SDF` can split the work it's currently doing dynamically when the runner wants it, e.g. you start assuming you're processing the whole file, then the runner tells you to split the remaining job and gives it to another node.

Comment: But I am not sure how well it is supported though, it is marked as feature complete: https://beam.apache.org/roadmap/portability/

You can reach to user@beam.apache.org or dev@beam.apache.org , people who have more context on `SDF` may help you there

Comment: Thanks! sent a detailed question to user@beam.apache.org. Let me know if you can see it successfully.